# Blender objects moving before it interacts with another object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Why is the cups falling earlier before it even interacts/hit with the object?

I have Deactivation Activated and I also have Applied the **Scale** of both objects.

[image: Sorry for the low quality]

.blend File: 
[image]

Comment: Could be the convex hull instead of mesh, could be margin….please provide blend files so we can tell you

Comment: Hello @Chris I already added the blend file. Thanks!